# SQL Server parsename equivalent

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Anyone know SQL Server [parsename function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: Use `regexp_substr()`; it is much more powerful (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm).

Comment: Something similar is doable in OCI - OCIDescribe. And I recall there was some function in some dbms_util.. package. But I can not recall its name. The function performed the same namespace search as Oracle does while compiling the query. So for resolve('FOO') it returned something like 'FOO' is public synonym for 'USER1.FOO'. Unfortunately I can not recall exact name.

Comment: Maybe it is in DBMS_DESCRIBE